Custom value in logging_config dict python
I made a bot python app using selenium and I mostly use logging for selenium logs. I want to add my own variable into formatter but I can't do it on my own. I was searching internet, trying different things but I always do something wrong and always get ValueError: Formatting field not found in record: 'username' error. I just want to add inGame username to the output.
import logging
import logging.handlers
import logging.config

HowrseUsername = "some_username"

class seleniumfilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        if "error" in record.getMessage() or record.getMessage().startswith("POST") or record.getMessage().startswith("Remote response"):
            return True
        return False

logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

logging_config = {
    "version": 1,
    "disabe_existing_loggers": False,
    "filters": {
        "seleniumfilter": {
        "()": "__main__.seleniumfilter"
        }
    },
    "formatters": {
        "simple": {
            "format": '%(username)s || %(asctime)s || %(levelname)s || %(name)s || %(message)s'
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "errorshandler": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "level": "ERROR",
            "formatter": "simple",
            "filename": "logs/errors.log",
            "encoding": 'utf-8',
            "maxBytes": 20000000,
            "backupCount": 2
        },
        "seleniumhandler": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "simple",
            "filename": "logs/seleniumlogs.log",
            "encoding": 'utf-8',
            "filters": ['seleniumfilter'],
            "maxBytes": 20000000,
            "backupCount": 2
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "root": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "handlers": [
                "errorshandler",
                "seleniumhandler"
            ]
        }
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(logging_config)

I tried doing formatter class, using LoggerAdapter etc. but I always get this error so I must be doing something wrong. Pls help.
